# Visible lines along Y-axis on Ender 3 Pro

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-3, petg, y-axis

I have a model that's placed on the bed exactly like on this picture:

[image: sample model placement]

I have constant quality degradation as the bed moves down to print in the upper left corner **(1)**.

Everything is fine on the X **(2)-(3)** side. It does not have any visible artifacts. All hell goes along the **(1)-(3)** curve:

[image: hell lines]

Top left corner **(1)**:

[image: top left corner]

On the way from **(1)** to **(2)** lines seem to disappear almost completely.

I used Cura slicer and these printing settings:

- stock ender firmware
- 0.2 mm layer height
- supports
- 2 bottom & top layers
- PETG 235 °C nozzle
- 80 °C bed
- walls x2
- 10 % infill gyroid
- ironing
- seam smart hiding
- 50 mm/s print speed
- 500 / 50 mm/s^2 acceleration / jerks

It looks like a mechanical issue, so I tried tightening/untightening bed bolts. It didn't help. They are a little bit tight, but not too much. The bed does not seem to be wobbling. Also, I tried the bed for wobbling in its top/bottom position. It looks fine along all the way.

What should I try next?

Extruder steps/mm are tweaked for this filament. Extruder produces exactly 97 mm of 100 mm of filament.

#### UPD

I decided to change my software/hardware settings step by step. This time I changed only my software settings to these:

- Speed: 30 mm/s
- Acceleration: 3000 mm/s^2
- Retract: 4 mm
- Combing: Not in Skin (previous print had the same value)
- Overhanging wall speed 100% (same as the previous print)

Corners have become much sharper and there is a lot less of bulging on the arc.

[image: arc]

However, by X-axis **(2) - (3)** I see more artifacts:

[image: x-axis bottom]

Y-axis has become better:

[image: y-axis bottom]

Currently, I don't have any visible or sensible bed / X play. I tuned rollers to have enough tension not to slip if rotate them separately. So, if I rotate the roller, it moves the whole bed or X carriage. I'll try increasing the tension a little bit and then I'll share the result.

#### UPD2

I've made belts a little bit tighter and decided to print a new model. The layer height is 0.3 mm. Also, I tried increasing temperature up to **240 °C** and changed the stock vent with a circular vent. The wall count is 50 to make the model solid. Coasting is off.

[image: x-axis]

[image: x-axis curve]

Now all artifacts are along the X-axis. There are many fewer of them at (1) than at (2). The model is a doorstep. On the build plate it's placed like this:

[image: doorstep build plate placement]

Now I think the problem has nothing to do with X/Y play and these two factors can be eliminated. I'll revert belt tensions back to their previous values and decrease the printing temperature down to 225-230 °C.

PS. USBASP is still in customs, so I'm doing all this on the stock firmware.

#### UPD3

I have finally figured out what was wrong. It was insufficient Z-belt tension on both sides. A close look at a DSLR camera shot gave me a clue: there was almost always a straight segment followed by a visible additional step down between layers.

There are still some artifacts but everything looks relatively tolerable now.

[image: after z-axis has been fixed]

Thanks to all of you guys!

Comment: On the Arc are retraction artifacts. What's your retraction setting?

Comment: @Trish, I have 6mm retract. I tried 2, 4, and decided to stop at 6mm. Otherwise, there was a lot of stringing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of different print quality problems going on here, but the biggest I see is the bulging and sagging at the corners of each layer. This is a result of extrusion not being a zero-delay linear function of extruder motor motion, but subject to compression/pressure. This causes excess extrusion when printing slows down (approaching and rounding a corner) and underextrusion just after speeding back up. There are several possible fixes:

- Upgrade to firmware with [Linear Advance](https://marlinfw.org/docs/features/lin_advance.html) and calibrate it for your material. I find PETG needs about K=1.4 on an Ender 3.
- Increase your acceleration limits (up to 3000 mm/s² should be ok for Ender 3) so that far less time is spent moving slow. You need to adjust the per-axis limits in config menu, not just the single acceleration setting in your slicer.
- Decrease your print speed so that there's less difference in cornering speed and nominal speed (50 mm/s is too high for PETG anyway in my experience; you'll get underextrusion and bad layer bonding).

Also make sure you don't have your slicer set to slowdown on overhangs, as it makes this phenomenon **far** worse.

The other surface artifacts I'm less sure about, and you should probably look for other answers about resolving them. Trish is right that the lines look like a retraction problem - material intended to be there got lost somewhere else. It's probably due to combing (skipping retraction inside the model and letting material ooze out there). I would set combing to "not in skin" and set the max combing distance to something very small (around or slightly less than 1 mm) and see if that fixes the problem. Combing is especially bad with PETG in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

I see some possible issues at work here:

1. Retraction issues on the arc. You might need to decrease your retraction length a little.
2. Your bed might have a little play. tighten the eccentric nuts a tiny bit.
3. As you are at it, check your X-belt, because accuracy on the Y move is affected by the accuracy of the X-head's position.